# What's intended by the semi-colon in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Purposely means both "on purpose, by design; intentionally, deliberately".

Why use a semi-colon here rather than a comma?

Comment: It separates two pairs of related concepts. A comma wouldn't display that structure.

Comment: It's dictionaryese, not standard punctuation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about a non-standard usage which is doubtless defined in the uncited dictionary.

Comment: Please do not post a comment in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't be sure until I know your context, I think this is a shorthand notation for multiple dictionary definitions, i.e.

*The dictionary definition of **purposely** is as follows:*

> 1. On purpose; by design
> 2. Intentionally; deliberately

Instead of numbering the definitions in an example like the above, whoever wrote this sentence decided to simply separate them in shorthand:

> *Purposely means "on purpose, by design; intentionally, deliberately"*

The *both* in your example is incorrect and unneccessary. *Both* would need to be followed by *and* in order to be clear and technically correct.

> *Purposely means both "On purpose; by design" **and** "intentionally; deliberately."*

In addition, as illustrated above, the commas would have to be replaced by either semicolons or hyphens in order to clarify that the 'and' separates the two definitions. I have also used separate quotations on the two definitions for further clarity.